# Linq query exception/error

Tags: vb.net, linq

Following is the code I get to achieve a list of Courses:

```
Dim Result As New List(Of WorkMateLib.CourseNameSpace.CoursesLib.Course)
    For Each cat As WorkMateLib.CourseNameSpace.CoursesLib.Category In Courses.CoursesOfferedMAIN.Values
        For Each c As WorkMateLib.CourseNameSpace.CoursesLib.Course In cat.Courses.Values
            Result.Add(c)
        Next
    Next
```

and it is working fine.   However I am trying to attempt to do the same with linq and the code is:

```
Result.AddRange(From k As WorkMateLib.CourseNameSpace.CoursesLib.Category In Courses.CoursesOfferedMAIN.Values Where Not k.CategoryName = "" Select k.Courses.Values.ToList())
```

But is throwing an error as follows:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[WorkMateLib.CourseNameSpace.CoursesLib+Category,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WorkMateLib.CourseNameSpace.CoursesLib+Course]]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WorkMateLib.CourseNameSpace.CoursesLib+Course]'.

Could you please help me better understand it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be equivalent.  Note that there's no need to create a list yourself.

```
Dim Result = Courses.CoursesOfferedMAIN.Values                    _
                    .SelectMany(Function(cat) cat.Courses.Values) _
                    .ToList
```

Comment: Mercado   man you really rock.  Thanks for helping.  I have been working with dictionary type for a long time and recently started to look at linq, your code is of real help in understanding the use of dictionary in a better perspective.  Thanks, now I can remove more lines of waste code from file. :D